# Android - IO Exception (java.net.socketexception: recvfrom failed: econnreset (connection reset by peer)

Tags: android

Uploading multiple images to server using Android HttpURLConnection, I have sent maximum 100 images... while uploading images to server irrespective of index location the below issue is coming,
java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

And I even tried Volley lib but no luck...

Can you suggest right Network library to handle this kind of issues or let us know your thoughts?